# Kimono Labs CSV Download

Tags: csv, format, kimono

I have made a Kimono Labs scrape, however when downloading to a CSV file the file skips blank cells which makes the data time consuming to tidy up.
Can someone advise how the data can be dowloaded to CSV and keep column format.

Comment: show your code first

Answer (score 0):

1. if this a bug - report to kimono
2. probably such it's just your data structure - I had no problems before - investigate other formats (does JSON also has the same problem?)